# Does anyone know if "Evaluating $apply as an Expand Option" is supported in asp.net core

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

Does anyone know if "Evaluating `$apply` as an Expand Option" as stated in [Odata extension for Data aggregation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs02/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs02.html#_Toc435016591) is supported in ASP.NET Core Web API in any way yet?

I don't seem to be able to get it to work, but that could be just me :)

What seems strange to me is that I can get the API to accept a query like:

```
.../ObjectType1(Id)?$expand=ObjectType2($apply=groupby((ObjectType2Type),aggregate(Id with countdistinct as total)))
```

but it doesn't do the actual `apply` part

Comment: Take a look here. https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1154 I think it's not implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ali

What seems strange to me is that I can get the api to accept a query like...

.../ObjectType1(Id)?$expand=ObjectType2($apply=groupby((ObjectType2Type),aggregate(Id with countdistinct as total)))

...but it dosent do the actual apply part

Comment: @Paul you can [edit] your question and update it